# How to reference page class from a code folder?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have an ASP.NET website written in VB.NET and trying to add MVC to it.

I managed to add controllers (to CS_Code folder) and make them running. However, I have to use some code from aspnet pages.

When I try to call method from page I ma having compile time error

```
public CustomerFrontend.DefaultForm DefaultForm { get; set; }
```

**Error:**

> The type or namespace name 'DefaultForm' could not be found  (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Page directive definition which proves than namespace is correct:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" ValidateRequest="false" 
                       EnableViewState="False" 
                       AutoEventWireup="false" 
                       Inherits="CustomerFrontend.DefaultForm" 
                       CodeFile="DefaultForm.aspx.vb" %>
```

Regardless the fact if I refer to fill name or short name.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this instead:

```
DefaultForm page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as DefaultForm;
if (page != null)
{
    page.MyMethod();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Is "CustomerFrontend" the namespace of your application?  Make sure you put the fully qualified path to the "DefaultForm" class.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.